# Using Morphia with Java EE

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, ejb, morphia

I am attempting to use Morphia as part of a web service I am creating using Java EE.

I read the morphia documentation about their DAO support which said:

> In a web application environment, we would probably use a dependency injection framework (like Guice or Spring) to inject the dependencies into the DAO, and then inject the DAO into a controller, so the controller would never directly deal with the gritty details.

Therefore I have an EJB marked with the `@Stateless` annotation (so that I can inject when I need it) that extends the `BasicDAO` morhpia provides as follows:

```
@Stateless
public class PlayerDAO extends BasicDAO<Player, ObjectId>{

    @EJB
    ConnectionFactory factory;

    public PlayerDAO(){};

    public PlayerDAO(Morphia morphia, MongoClient mongo){
    super(mongo, morphia, "testdb");
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to provide the constructor that takes the `Morphia` and `MongoClient` parameters and calls the `super` constructor, which then means I also need to provide a no-args constructor to satisfy Java EE's requirements.

When I add this constructor NetBeans shows the error:

> public PlayerDAO(){};
>      constructor BasicDAO.BasicDAO(Datastore) is not applicable
>        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>      constructor BasicDAO.BasicDAO(MongoClient,Morphia,String) is not applicable
>        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>      constructor BasicDAO.BasicDAO(Class,Datastore) is not applicable
>        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>      constructor BasicDAO.BasicDAO(Class,MongoClient,Morphia,String) is not applicable
>        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Is there a way to get around this behaviour, or should I be taking a different approach in order to use MongoDB as part of a java ee web service?

Answer (score 0):

This is what we did, worked great.  The implementation below is CDI only (deployed to Tomcat), but also works with `@Stateless` beans.  We let `Mongo` and `Morphia` be `@Produce`d by a factory.  The `@QConfig` annotated name is produced by a producer that reads a `.properties` file from the class path that contains the MongoDB database name.

```
public interface EntityDao<T, K> {
    T findById(K id);
    K save(T object);
    T update(T object); // returns an up-to-date version of the entity 
}

public class BaseDaoMorphiaImpl<T extends BaseEntity, K>
    implements EntityDao<T, K>, Serializable {

    @Inject
    private @QConfig String mongoDbName;
    @Inject
    private @QMongo Instance<Mongo> mongo;
    @Inject
    private @QMorphia Instance<Morphia> morphia;

    // BasicDAO is not serializeable; always use wrapper getBasicDao()
    private transient BasicDAO<T, K> basicDao;
    private Class clazz;

    public BaseDaoMorphiaImpl(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setupBasicDao();
    }

    protected BasicDAO<T, K> getBasicDao() {
        if (basicDao == null)
            setupBasicDao();
        return basicDao;
    }

    private void setupBasicDao() {
        basicDao = new BasicDAO<T, K>(clazz, mongo.get(), morphia.get(), mongoDbName);
        basicDao.ensureIndexes();
    }

    @Override
    public T findById(K id) {
        return getBasicDao().get(id); 
    }

    @Override
    public K save(T o) {
        Key<T> key = getBasicDao().save(o);
        return (K) key.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T o) {
         return findById((K) o.getId());
    }

    protected QueryResults<T> find( Query<T> query ) {
         return getBasicDao().find(query);
    }

    protected T findOne( Query<T> query ) {
        return getBasicDao().findOne(query);
    }    

    protected Query<T> createQuery() {
        return getBasicDao().getDatastore().createQuery(clazz);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public interface UserDao extends EntityDao<User, ObjectId> {
    User findByEmail( String email );
    User findByName( String name );
    List<User> findAll();
}

public class UserDaoMorphiaImpl extends BaseDaoMorphiaImpl<User, ObjectId> implements     UserDao {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    public UserDaoMorphiaImpl() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        Datastore ds = getBasicDao().getDatastore();
        User res = ds.find(User.class).filter("email = ", email).get();
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByName(String name) {
        Datastore ds = getBasicDao().getDatastore();
        User res = ds.find(User.class).filter("name = ", name).get();
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return getBasicDao().find().asList();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectId save(User user) {       
        return super.save(user);
    }    
}
```

For more specific queries, you can use something like this:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Document> fetchNewest( int start, int count ) {
    return find(createQuery().order("-uploadDate").offset(start).limit(count)).iterator();
}
```